# C# how to use 'await' to wait for connection for an Asynchronous Client Socket

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous

My method that starts my Asynchronous Client Socket blocks when it calls .BeginConnect() while waiting for connection.

I want the method to be async and want to 'await' connection instead of blocking, so that caller can continue while waiting for connection.

```
        public static async Task start_connection() 
    {  
        // Connect to a remote device.  
        try {  
            IPAddress ipAddress =  IPAddress.Parse( App.SYSTEM_HUB_IP );
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);  

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
            Socket client_Socket = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,  
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);  


                // .BeginConnect blocks.
```

<<<<<<<< 'await' ON NEXT LINE CAUSES COMPILER ERROR

```
            client_Socket.BeginConnect( remoteEP,   new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client_Socket);                 connectDone.WaitOne();  

        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  
    }
```

I do not see any solution for async client connection in "This question already has an answer here". All I see there is async listener (ie. server, not client). My socket service is already async. But I can find no example of async client initiating connection.

Specifically, how do I use async/wait to prevent .BeginConnect from blocking?

Comment: What about ConnectAsync()? Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.connectasync?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @croxy That has the same fundamental problem.

Comment: I do not see any solution for async client connection in "This question already has an answer here".  All I see there is async listener (ie. server, not client).  My socket service is already async.  But I can find no example of async client initiating connection.